# Check for use of comma in multiple strings passed as parameters in Powershell

Tags: arrays, string, powershell, validation, parameters

I have a script that takes two parameters: one takes a single string, the other takes two strings. For the script to function correctly both strings have to be separated by a comma. When using the script if the user does not use the comma, Powershell throws and error which does not say anything about using the comma. How can I customize that error message. I've tried with ValidateScript but i can`t make it to work. This is what I have:

```
Param (
      [Parameter(Mandatory=$false, ParameterSetName="OptionA")]
      [String] $OptionA,

      [Parameter(Mandatory=$false, ParameterSetName="OptionB")]
      [ValidateCount(2,2)]
      [ValidateScript({
          if ($_.ToString().Contains(",")) {
            $true
          } else {
              Throw "$_ use comma to separate the two strings!"  
          }
      })]
      [String[]] $OptionB
)

if ($OptionA) {
      Write-Host $OptionA
      return
}

if ($OptionB) {
      Write-Host $OptionB
      return
}

Write-Host "Not a valid parameter!"
```

EDIT: So I've tried one of the solutions, the one by @mklement0 and keep getting the error message thrown by Powershell.

[image: Error screenshot]

Any suggestions?

Comment: This is what happens if you quietly edit your question in response to answers that were given _without notifying the user whose answers you're responding to_:  That user is likely to never see your update, and can therefore not help with your follow-up question. In this case, I _happened to_ see your update (see my updated answer), but in the future, I suggest providing feedback directly on the answer(s) that provided a step toward the desired solution.

Answer (score 0):

PowerShell *itself* parses `,`-separated tokens that make up an array-valued command argument into an *array*, so that your `[String[]]`-typed `$OptionB` parameter  already sees the `,`-separated tokens as individual array elements.

However, the script block passed to the `[ValidateScript()]` attribute is invoked *for each element* of the array being passed, so you cannot validate the array *as a whole* there.

Therefore, your only option is to perform the validation in your script's *body*, after all parameters have been bound:

```
param (
      [Parameter(Mandatory=$false, ParameterSetName="OptionA")]
      [String] $OptionA,

      [Parameter(Mandatory=$false, ParameterSetName="OptionB")]
      [String[]] $OptionB
)

if ($PSCmdlet.ParameterSetName -eq 'OptionB' -and $OptionB.Count -ne 2) {
  Throw "Exactly two comma-separated strings must be passed."  
}
```

Note that if you want to pass arguments *positionally*, more work is needed: By default, *all* parameters are positional, so that an invocation such as `./script.ps1 foo` is *ambiguous*, because it can bind to either `-OptionA` or `-Option B`.

To resolve this ambiguity, define your function as follows, which will bind `./script.ps1 foo` to `-OptionA`, and a array-valued argument such as `./script.ps1 foo, bar` to `-OtionB`:

```
[CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName='OptionA')]
param (
      [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=0, ParameterSetName="OptionA")]
      [String] $OptionA,

      [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=0, ParameterSetName="OptionB")]
      [String[]] $OptionB
)

if ($PSCmdlet.ParameterSetName -eq 'OptionB' -and $OptionB.Count -ne 2) {
  Throw "Exactly two comma-separated strings must be passed."  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible setup using only a single Option parameter.

Note: Wrapped in function for testing purposes.

```
Function Test {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param (
      [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
        [string[]] $Option
    )

    Switch ($option.Count) {
      1  {"Single Parameter"}
      2  {"Two Parameters"}
      Default {"More than two Parameters"}
    } #End Switch

} #End Function
 
Clear-Host
  
Test "Parameter 1","Parameter 2"
```

You can choose to let run as it stands since it will prompt for missing parameter or you can change to Mandatory=$False and add validation for Null.